# How to define a termination order for the function with fmmap_keys?

Tags: isabelle

I'm trying to define a supremum operation for a datatype based on `fmap`:

```
datatype t = A | B | C "(nat, t) fmap"

abbreviation
  "supc f xs ys ≡
    fmmap_keys
      (λk x. f x (the (fmlookup ys k)))
      (fmfilter (λk. k |∈| fmdom ys) xs)"

fun sup_t (infixl "⊔" 65) where
  "A ⊔ _ = A"
| "B ⊔ B = B"
| "B ⊔ _ = A"
| "C xs ⊔ C ys = C (supc (⊔) xs ys)"
| "C xs ⊔ _ = A"
```

And get the error:

```
Unfinished subgoals:
(a, 1, <):
 1. ⋀ys x. size (the (fmlookup ys x)) < Suc (∑x∈fset (fset_of_fmap ys). Suc (case x of (a, x) ⇒ size x))
(a, 1, <=):
 1. ⋀ys x. size (the (fmlookup ys x)) ≤ Suc (∑x∈fset (fset_of_fmap ys). Suc (case x of (a, x) ⇒ size x))
(a, 2, <):
 1. ⋀xs xa. size xa < Suc (∑x∈fset (fset_of_fmap xs). Suc (case x of (a, x) ⇒ size x))
(a, 2, <=):
 1. ⋀xs xa. size xa ≤ Suc (∑x∈fset (fset_of_fmap xs). Suc (case x of (a, x) ⇒ size x))
(a, 3, <):
 1. False
Calls:
  a) (C xs, C ys) ~> (xa, the (fmlookup ys x))
Measures:
  1) λp. size (snd p)
  2) λp. size (fst p)
  3) size
Result matrix:
    1  2  3 
a:  ?  ?  <=

Could not find lexicographic termination order.
```

If I simplify the function passed as the first argument to `fmmap_keys`, then the error disappears:

```
abbreviation
  "supc f xs ys ≡
    fmmap_keys
      (λk x. x)
      (fmfilter (λk. k |∈| fmdom ys) xs)"
```

So I guess, that the error is caused by a complex recursive call of `sup_t`. The only possible source of non-termination is structures of the form `C («[x ↦ C (...)]»)`. But an external `C` is removed on each recursive call so the function should terminate.

Could you suggest how to fix this error or redefine `supc`?

---

**UPDATE**

Here is an alternative definition:

```
abbreviation
  "supc f xs ys ≡
    fmap_of_list (map
      (λ(k, x). (k, f x (the (fmlookup ys k))))
      (sorted_list_of_fmap (fmfilter (λk. k |∈| fmdom ys) xs)))"

function sup_t (infixl "⊔" 65) where
  "A ⊔ _ = A"
| "B ⊔ x = (if x = B then B else A)"
| "C xs ⊔ x = (case x of C ys ⇒ C (supc sup_t xs ys) | _ ⇒ A)"
  by pat_completeness auto
termination
  apply auto
```

I have to prove the following subgoal:

```
⋀a b. sup_t_dom (a, b)
```

How to unfold `sup_t_dom`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please find a potentially viable solution in the code listing below.

---

**Background**

The issue that you have encountered is described partially in the document "Defining Recursive Functions in Isabelle/HOL" written by Alexander Krauss (also known as "Tutorial on Function Definitions" in Isabelle documentation) and more comprehensively in the PhD thesis ["Automating Recursive Definitions and Termination Proofs in Higher-Order Logic"](https://www21.in.tum.de/~krauss/papers/krauss-thesis.pdf) that was also written by Alexander Krauss. In particular, see Chapter 4 in the tutorial and section 3.3 in the thesis.

---

**Size of `t`**

From the aforementioned references, it is possible to infer that one way to prove the termination of `sup_t` is to provide a suitable measure function. In this case, it is apparent that a measure function that is associated with the size of the datatype might be suitable for the application. Unfortunately, `t` is a nested type and (in this particular case) the default function `size` does not seem to capture the recursive nature of the datatype - this is not always the case (see section 3.3.2 in the thesis).

As the first step, I provided a new size function for `t`. The definition is based on the total number of `C`s contained within `x::t` (the definition should be easy to modify to suit your needs for other applications).

---

**Measure and Termination**

I found that the measure function `(λ(xs, ys). size ys)` is suitable to prove the termination of `sup_t`. Also, this measure function is used in Isabelle to prove the termination of `sup_t` if it is declared with the command `fun`. However, in this case, it was not possible to prove that the arguments of recursive calls indeed decrease with respect to the relation that was established by the measure automatically. However, it would be sufficient to show that `"size (the (fmlookup x k)) < size (C x)"`.

Unfortunately, the function `supc` (as stated in your question) is not self-certifying with respect to the property that the first argument that is passed to `(λk x. f x (the (fmlookup ys k)))` is in the domain of `ys`. Therefore, `the (fmlookup ys k)` can take the value `the None`. Given that this issue seems to be nearly orthogonal to the main topic of the question, I decided not to investigate it further and made an amendment to the function `supc` to ensure that it is guaranteed to return a concrete term of `t` (you may want to prove explicitly that the function specified below is identical in its behaviour to the one that you provided in your question or, otherwise, provide a better alternative that would be self-certifying):

```
abbreviation
  "supc f xs ys ≡
    fmmap_keys
      (λk x. if (k |∈| fmdom ys) then (f x (the (fmlookup ys k))) else A)
      (fmfilter (λk. k |∈| fmdom ys) xs)"
```

After this modification, the previous goal `"size (the (fmlookup x k)) < size (C x)"` was changed to `"(k |∈| fmdom ys) ⟹ size (the (fmlookup x k)) < size (C x)"`, which could be easily proven (see lemma `measure_cond`). If this lemma is declared as an introduction rule then the termination of `sup_t` can be proven automatically if it is declared with the command `fun`.

---

**Remarks**

The main reason why I decided to investigate this issue and provide an answer is that I knew very little about some of the main topics of the question and wanted to learn them. As a result, my answer may be suboptimal due to the lack of experience/knowledge in these areas. Of course, if you also have doubts about whether the solution that I proposed here is optimal for the application, it may be worth trying to ask the question on the mailing list.

---

```
theory termination_problem
  imports 
    Complex_Main
    "HOL-Library.Finite_Map"
begin

datatype (plugins del: "size") t = A | B | C "(nat, t) fmap"

abbreviation "tcf ≡ (λ v::(nat × nat). (λ r::nat. snd v + r))"

interpretation tcf: comp_fun_commute tcf
proof 
  fix x y
  show "tcf y ∘ tcf x = tcf x ∘ tcf y"
  proof -
    fix z
    have "(tcf y ∘ tcf x) z = snd y + snd x + z" by auto
    also have "(tcf x ∘ tcf y) z = snd y + snd x + z" by auto
    ultimately have "(tcf y ∘ tcf x) z = (tcf x ∘ tcf y) z" by auto
    then show "(tcf y ∘ tcf x) = (tcf x ∘ tcf y)" by auto
  qed
qed

instantiation t :: size 
begin

primrec t_size :: "t ⇒ nat" where
AR: "t_size A = 0" |
BR: "t_size B = 0" |
CR: "t_size (C x) = 
  (Suc 0) + ffold tcf 0 (fset_of_fmap (fmmap t_size x))" 

definition size_t where
size_t_def: "size_t = t_size"

instance ..

end

lemma ffold_rec_exp:
  assumes "k |∈| fmdom x"
    and "ky = (k, the (fmlookup (fmmap t_size x) k))"
  shows "ffold tcf 0 (fset_of_fmap (fmmap t_size x)) = 
        tcf ky (ffold tcf 0 ((fset_of_fmap (fmmap t_size x)) |-| {|ky|}))"
  using assms tcf.ffold_rec by auto

lemma elem_le_ffold:
  assumes "k |∈| fmdom x"
  shows "t_size (the (fmlookup x k)) < 
        (Suc 0) + ffold tcf 0 (fset_of_fmap (fmmap t_size x))"
  using ffold_rec_exp assms by auto

lemma measure_cond [intro]:
  assumes "k |∈| fmdom x"
  shows "size (the (fmlookup x k)) < size (C x)"
  using assms elem_le_ffold size_t_def by auto

abbreviation
  "supc f xs ys ≡
    fmmap_keys
      (λk x. if (k |∈| fmdom ys) then (f x (the (fmlookup ys k))) else A)
      (fmfilter (λk. k |∈| fmdom ys) xs)"

fun sup_t (infixl "⊔" 65) where
  "A ⊔ _ = A"
| "B ⊔ x = (if x = B then B else A)"
| "C xs ⊔ x = (case x of C ys ⇒ C (supc sup_t xs ys) | _ ⇒ A)"

(*Examples*)

abbreviation "list_1 ≡ fmap_of_list [(1::nat, B)]"
abbreviation "list_2 ≡ fmap_of_list [(1::nat, A), (2::nat, A)]"
value "(C list_1) ⊔ (C list_2)"

abbreviation "list_3 ≡ fmap_of_list [(1::nat, B), (3::nat, A)]"
abbreviation "list_4 ≡ fmap_of_list [(2::nat, A), (4::nat, B)]"
value "(C list_3) ⊔ (C list_4)"

abbreviation "list_5 ≡ fmap_of_list [(1::nat, B), (2::nat, B)]"
abbreviation "list_6 ≡ fmap_of_list [(2::nat, B), (4::nat, B)]"
value "(C list_5) ⊔ (C list_6)"

abbreviation "list_7 ≡ 
  fmap_of_list [(1::nat, B), (2::nat, C list_5), (3::nat, A)]"
abbreviation "list_8 ≡ fmap_of_list [(2::nat, B), (4::nat, B)]"
value "(C list_7) ⊔ (C list_8)"

abbreviation "list_9 ≡ 
  fmap_of_list [(1::nat, B), (2::nat, C list_5), (3::nat, A)]"
abbreviation "list_10 ≡ fmap_of_list [(2::nat, C list_6), (3::nat, B)]"
value "(C list_9) ⊔ (C list_10)"

end
```

Comment: This time, while answering your question, I have also acquired a substantial amount of new knowledge: thank you for providing an interesting question.

Comment: I have made minor amendments: it is not necessary to prove termination explicitly if `measure_cond` is declared as an introduction rule.